# Nativescript 4 - Http module converts + (plus sign) into empty space

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm wondering why this plugin is doing this ?

```
http.request({
    url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',

    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    content: 'email=d+e@test.uk&password=password'

}).then(function(response) {
    result = response.content.toJSON();
    console.log('Https.request response', result)
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Https.request error', error)
});
```

The result of console log will be:

email=d e@test.uk&password=password (+ has gone).

Any ideas why this plugin attempts is converting this sign ?
If i replace + with %2B then this will be valid and accepted string from My API, but this is not the case. I can't check what user is typing, so it's confusing.

Thanks for help.

Documentation of Http module [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http).

Comment: you could try `var content = encodeURI('email=d+e@test.uk&password=password')` and then `content: content`

Comment: Thank you for tip @mast3rd3mon but the result is the same...Console log shows empty space.: email": "d e@test.uk"

Comment: But i see that encodeURIComponent transformed this well. So thanks for help.

Comment: that seems odd, `encodeURI` should have changed the `+` to the code form, ie `%2B`